# How to combine a link to a button which should change the state dynamically?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to input a button to my react page which should download an attachment(specifically a SSRS Report). This link has a variable(order number parameter) which changes with the `array.map` for each data row. Here's how I tried to do it but the issue I have is in the link I cannot insert the variable. Since it's not letting me use backticks how should I make this work?

My code:

```
{data.map((alldata) => (
    <ul key={alldata.id}> 
      <li><input id={alldata.id} defaultValue={alldata.supplier_email} onChange={e => setInput1(e.target.value)} size="35"/></li> 
      <li><input id={alldata.id} defaultValue={alldata.confirmed} onChange={e => setInput2(e.target.value)} size="35"/></li>
      <Button component={Link} to="http://sqlserver15/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%%2fESE_PRODUCTION%2fEvent+Manager%2fPurchase_Order&ord_no=${ordernumber}&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF">
        Posts
      </Button>
      <button id={alldata.ID} onClick={handleUpdate}>Update</button>
    </ul>
))}
```

So in above code the `to="http://sqlserver15/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%%2fESE_PRODUCTION%2fEvent+Manager%2fPurchase_Order&ord_no=${ordernumber}&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF"` is the place where I need to change dynamically, specifically the `ord_no=${ordernumber}` part. But I cannot use `${}` to dyncamically change it since Material-UI button element won't let use backticks.

Comment: If I read this properly this will produce a `<ul>` with a direct `<button>` child which is invalid HTML re: 0 or more - see "Permitted content" here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In map function you can generate the link and then just add to `to` prop.

```
 {data.map((alldata) => {
        const _link = `http://sqlserver15/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%%2fESE_PRODUCTION%2fEvent+Manager%2fPurchase_Order&ord_no=${ordernumber}&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF`
   return <ul key={alldata.id}> 
              <li><input id={alldata.id} defaultValue={alldata.supplier_email} onChange={e => setInput1(e.target.value)} size="35"/></li> 
              <li><input id={alldata.id} defaultValue={alldata.confirmed} onChange={e => setInput2(e.target.value)} size="35"/></li>
              <Button component={Link} to={_link}>
                   Posts
              </Button>
              <button id={alldata.ID} onClick={handleUpdate}>Update</button>
           </ul>
 })}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
This code should work for you

```
{data.map((alldata) => (
     <ul key={alldata.id}> 
         <li><input id={alldata.id} defaultValue={alldata.supplier_email} onChange={e => setInput1(e.target.value)} size="35"/></li> 
         <li><input id={alldata.id} defaultValue={alldata.confirmed} onChange={e => setInput2(e.target.value)} size="35"/></li>
         <Button component={Link} to=`http://sqlserver15/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%%2fESE_PRODUCTION%2fEvent+Manager%2fPurchase_Order&ord_no=${ordernumber}&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF`>
                        Posts
         </Button>
         <button id={alldata.ID} onClick={handleUpdate}>Update</button>
     </ul>
))}
```

Comment: Template Literals are literally not working here. That is my question indeed. But the way @ShoaibAh explained did work. Thank you very much!